# How to connect to multiple databases in a single PHP page?

Tags: php, mysql, multiple-databases

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you connect to multiple MySQL databases on a single webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274892/how-do-you-connect-to-multiple-mysql-databases-on-a-single-webpage)

If I want to connect to one db do some query, and then later do another query from another DB. How do I do it? Do I just

```
 mysql_pconnect("host:3306", "user", "password") or die(mysql_error());
 mysql_select_db("Test") or die(mysql_error());

//do some query

 mysql_pconnect("host2:3306", "user", "password") or die(mysql_error());
 mysql_select_db("Test") or die(mysql_error());

//do another query
```

Is that how you do it? A couple of questions. Notice I used pconnect, does that affect calling it twice on the same page? Also, do I have to close the connection for the first one before calling the second one?

Comment: Copy of [this - How do you connect to multiple MySQL databases on a single webpage?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274892/how-do-you-connect-to-multiple-mysql-databases-on-a-single-webpage).

Answer (score 4):

You need to store database connection link in separate variable. For example

```
 $connection_1 = mysql_connect("host:3306", "user", "password") or die(mysql_error());
 mysql_select_db("Test", $connection_1) or die(mysql_error());

 $connection_2 = mysql_pconnect("host2:3306", "user", "password") or die(mysql_error());
 mysql_select_db("Test", $connection_2) or die(mysql_error());

 mysql_query("your query", $connection_1); // run query for first connection
 mysql_query("your query", $connection_2); // run query for second connection
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the resource returned from mysql_connect and use it when doing mysql_select_db.

```
$res1 = mysql_pconnect(...);
mysql_select_db("Test", $res1);

$res2 = mysql_pconnect(...);
mysql_select_db("Test", $res2);
```

Then use $res1 or $res2 when querying the corresponding db.

```
mysql_query("select * from test_table", $res1);

mysql_query("select * from test_table", $res2);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is that how you do it?

This will leave your script with two open connections to different hosts until it ends.

You may reuse either of these connections by calling `mysql_pconnect` again.

> Notice I used `pconnect`, does that affect calling it twice on the same page?

From the [**docs**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-pconnect.php):

> > The function would first try to find a (persistent) link that's already open *with the same host, username and password*

Since your hosts are different, there will be two different connections

> Also, do I have to close the connection for the first one before calling the second one?

You cannot explicitly close a connection open with `mysql_pconnect`.

Answer (score 0):

You did RTM, right, because you're not using the `$link_identifier`?

http://us.php.net/mysql_select_db :

> `bool mysql_select_db ( string $database_name [, resource $link_identifier ] )`
>
> Sets the current active database on the server that's associated with the specified link identifier. Every subsequent call to mysql_query() will be made on the active database.
>
> Parameters
>
> `database_name`
>   The name of the database that is to be selected.
>
> `link_identifier` The MySQL connection.
>
> If the link identifier is not specified, the last link opened by mysql_connect() is assumed. If no such link is found, it will try to create one as if mysql_connect() was called with no arguments. If no connection is found or established, an E_WARNING level error is generated.

Whenever you have use the pconnect, you're sharing the connection (not only within the page, but possibly with other pages) -- in your case here, don't do that.  You want isolated links, therefore isolated transactions.  You should probably consider `mysql_connect` instead, and explicitly using the `new_link` parameter.  Lastly, use the `$link_identifier` explicitly, so you are clear what you are connecting to.