# PHP - Application with multiple databases

Tags: php, mysql, database, performance, database-design

I am currently working on a **large application** that will be used by **many people** each having **a large amount of data**. I thought to manage these multiple users through a single database but I am asked to create a **separate database for each new user that is registered.** Now what I am wondering is : **is it a good idea** to do so i.e. having the app create a separate database for each new user that gets registered and manage it's data through it? What will be the **performance issues,** if any?

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4161292/how-to-use-multiple-database-using-php

Comment: @Chandresh is it? Have you even read my question?

Comment: Separate db for each user might be bad idea, but you can user limit db with user id interval. For example, the users that have id 1-100 will connect to db1, 101-200 will connect to db2

Comment: I think we need more info to properly assess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separate DB for each new registered user might be bad idea. You can do it like this;

> Put 100 users in each separate db. 1-100 => DB1, 101-200 => DB2, n, n+100 => DBn

You can keep a table for which id interval will be connect to which db. By doing this, you can lower db load. 100 users for each db is just an example. You need to use such a structure for a system that has lots of users.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is **create a separate database for each new user** is a **wonderfool** idea.you must set appropiate indexes over the table and you will get good performance