# How to Create Search Engine For Multiple Database With Indexing

Tags: php, mysql, search-engine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you connect to multiple MySQL databases on a single webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274892/how-do-you-connect-to-multiple-mysql-databases-on-a-single-webpage)

I am building a search engine for my website, I have 6 databases with many tables.

For multiple database I know I have to build a index file containing information from all database and tables.

I know how to build a search engine for database in PHP and MySQL,

Connect to  multiple database

```
mysql_connect(“hostname”, “username”, “password”);
mysql_select_db(“database1”);

mysql_connect(“hostname”, “username”, “password”);
mysql_select_db(“database2”);
```

and query like this

```
"(SELECT * from database1.search_table WHERE MATCH (title, link) AGAINST(‘keyword’))
  Union All 
 (SELECT * from database2.search_table WHERE MATCH (title, link) AGAINST(‘keyword’)"
```

I want to do it by making an index file.

Please suggest any good tutorial or method for this, I google many times but no good results.

Comment: yes then if i use UNION ALL in query, the resulting query will become too large, so i want to make a single index file which store all my databases information. how to make that index file. should i make another database containing all data from databases

Comment: I don't think you are able to execute a single query over multiple databases - I think you'll have to make individual queries to wach on and then combine the data yourself.

Comment: also my question is not duplicate as i am asking about making search engine not the way to connect  multiple database. i know ho to connect to multiple databases.

Comment: What you do once you have the multiple connections is not related to this question... You need a way to connect to multiple databases - and you can find the answer in the link I posted.

Answer (score 0):

I think of three ways to do this:
1-st You can user multiple database connection. That's the heaviest way to do this, because it'll increase the connections to the server.
2-nd You can just switch the chosen database. 
3-rd You can make your queries database independent by selecting the database in the query. Here's an example  :

```
SELECT * FROM `database`.`table` WHERE `database`.`table`.`column`='something'
```

I personally think that the third way is the best.