# Connecting to 2 databases at the same time to copy a field to a second database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a field in my table that I need to move to a completely different database. At this point I have 1 database `db1` that has `db1table` that has all the data, and an empty database `db2` that has `db2table`.

db1 table looks like this:

```
id    other_db_id     data_to_be_moved
---------------------------------------
1     NULL            data
2     NULL            data 
3     NULL            data 
4     NULL            data
5     NULL            data
```

db2 table looks like this:

```
id      data
--------------
empty
```

I usually use an ORM to access the database, but this time I'm doing it with plain mysql and php, so need a little help, especially with how I'd connect to 2 databases at the same time.

What I'd like to do is select the first 10 records from `db1 table`, read the field `data_to_be_moved` and use it to create a new record in `db2 table`. Then get the id of the newly inserted record and insert back in the original database as field `other_db_id`.

The way I'm connecting to a single database is this. How will I access both databases at the same time?

```
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "db1user","db1pass");
mysql_select_db("db1", $connection);
```

and I'm selecting the first 10 records to be manipulated as follows:

```
Select * From table Where Id BETWEEN 5 AND 10;
```

but I'm not sure how to proceed with the switching of the databases to achieve what I described above.

Comment: Try to look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274892/how-do-you-connect-to-multiple-mysql-databases-on-a-single-webpage

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to know how to handle multiple databases.
The following video will explain how to deal whit two (or more) databases: [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=bfnCEmGvY5k#!)

Answer (score 1):

You could store the intermediate values into a PHP variable, then switch database and do your thing.

Answer (score 0):

If the databases are on same server you can access both tables at same time by using syntax:

```
insert into db2.db2table
select other_db_id, data_to_be_moved
from db1.db1table;
```

This requires that the login has at least select access to other database.

If the databases are on different server, you can use federated table:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/federated-use.html

Answer (score 0):

Um,

```
$connection2 = mysql_connect("localhost", "db2user","db2pass");
```