# Using multiple database on my web page on same host

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection

I just referenced [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274892/how-do-you-connect-to-multiple-mysql-databases-on-a-single-webpage) answer and what I preferred was very first solution, now the issue is he has given an information for `mysql_()` but am using `mysqli_()`, so using 4th parameter as true, I select the database when user logs in, the moment he logs in he gets redirected to respective page but it is showing that connection was actively refused. any Idea how I can use 2 database, 1 is my default engine database which I need to keep it on for running my framework and second database to run respective scripts according to the user logged in...

What am trying is this

```
<?php
    $database_connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'engine');
    if(!$database_connect) {
        die ('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '. mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    if(isset($_SESSION['system_id'])) {
        $system_database = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', $_SESSION['system_name'], true);
        if(!$system_database) {
            die ('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '. mysqli_connect_error());
        }
    }
?>
```

P.S I want a procedural way

Comment: Don't refuse the connection?

Comment: why don't you connect both database and simply use `mysqli_query($database_connection, "Query");`?

Comment: @Mr.Alien shit that worked, thanks, please post it as an answer so that I can mark it correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need any extra parameters, simply do it like this

```
<?php
    $database_connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'engine');
    if(!$database_connect) {
        die ('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '. mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    if(isset($_SESSION['system_id'])) {
        $system_database = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', $_SESSION['system_name']);
        if(!$system_database) {
            die ('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '. mysqli_connect_error());
        }
    }

//Now whatever query you write, just do it like this

$access = mysqli_query($database_connection_var, "/*Query Goes Here*/"); //Will get database name from $database_connection_var

$access2 = mysqli_query($database_connection_var2, "/*Query Goes Here*/"); //Will get database name from $database_connection_var2
?>
```