# Loading WordPress core files externally causes rest of site to use wordpress mysql connection

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a separate site & wordpress installed onto that, but WP only resides in the `blog/` directory; they both use SEPARATE databases.

Now, I want to load the WP core files so I can load up some WP specific stuff on the homepage, so I went ahead & tried the below..

```
// Include wordpress core
require(WP_ROOT_PATH . 'wp-load.php');
```

Now I am getting database errors saying stuff like `database1.table1` doesn't exist. (Note these are example names only).

This is likely because now wordpress has opened it's own database connection & now the rest of the site is now running it's queries under the new connection.

The only ways to fix this that I can think of are..

- To add the database resource you want to use to all database calls
- Load the WP data via an iframe so that you only need to load the WP files & hence avoid the other problems

Is there anything else I can do apart from the above!?

Comment: How do you connect to your mysql db?  Are you using  link identifier? You can have multiple connections if you use different link identifiers: http://stackoverflow.com/a/274919/870729

Comment: The main site runs off some custom software which I have been doing a lot of customizations on, however it doesn't use link identifiers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try coding what you need in a separate file from the main site like so:

```
// Include wordpress core
require(WP_ROOT_PATH . 'wp-load.php');

//Get wp content here

// close wordpress database connection
mysql_close($wpdb->dbh);
```

Then `include` this file whenever you need the content in your main site. If `include` doesn't work you could use:

```
echo file_get_contents("filename.php")
```

Comment: I'll give that a try & see how I go. :)

Comment: Had to do the wordpress stuff BEFORE the other script opened the connection to the other database, but other than that this worked fine. :)