# two mysqli connections simultaneously

Tags: php, object, mysqli, querying

I tried to alter OOP script presented here:

to handle two databases at once (depending on function needs), but it seems not to work at all. I get an error message:
mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in ...DAL.php on line 60

```
private function dbconnect($usedb)
{
    switch($usedb)
    {
        case '':
        echo "Error choosing database to operate on.";
        break;
        case '1':
        $conn = new mysqli(DB1_HOST, DB1_USER, DB1_PASSWORD,DB1_DB) or die ("<br>Could not connect to MySQL server");
        //mysqli_select_db(DB1_DB,$conn) or die ("<br>Could not select the main database.");
        return $conn;
        break;
        case '2':
        $conn = new mysqli(DB2_HOST, DB2_USER, DB2_PASSWORD,DB2_DB) or die ("<br>Could not connect to MySQL server");
        //mysqli_select_db(DB2_DB,$conn) or die ("<br>Could not select the client database.");
        return $conn;
        break;
    }
}

private function query($usedb,$sql)
{
    $this->dbconnect($usedb);  
    $res = mysqli_query($sql);
```

Can this work eventually? How to handle two databases at once if called from a single function that is making querying much easier? What I do wrong?

Comment: What does the error message say? Have you looked at the documentation to see what parameters mysqli_query needs?

Comment: `mysqli_query` first parameter should be a `mysqli` instance.

Comment: Just add `$usedb` to `mysqli_query` like this, `mysqli_query($userdb, $sql)`

Comment: $sql variable contains the exact sql statement to be processed.

This code is based on:
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/simple-php-class-based-querying/

Comment: Also, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274892/how-do-you-connect-to-multiple-mysql-databases-on-a-single-webpage/45688265#45688265

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code:

```
private function query($usedb,$sql)
{
$this->dbconnect($usedb);  
$res = mysqli_query($sql);
```

Should be like:

```
private function query($usedb,$sql)
{
$conn = $this->dbconnect($usedb);  
$res = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

mysqli_close($conn); //dont forget to close it
```

And in you dbconnect function you should use procedural style:

```
return $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
```

Comment: Well, the worst problem is, that even now, I get error like:

"mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given"

How constant, same as first database name, can be a string? Should I convert this to an object?

Comment: are you using object style on yur function and procedural style outside....you change your code like the return $link y posted on my answer?

Comment: Robert Rozas, you've been almost exact with your answer. This totally works for me:

    private function query($usedb,$sql)
    {
        $conn = $this->dbconnect($usedb);
        $res = $conn->query($sql);

Answer (score 1):

You don't reconnect to the database every time, you save the link. This is one way to do it.

```
$dbs= array(1=>dbconnect(1), 2=>dbconnect(2));
private function query($usedb,$sql)
{
     global $dbs;
     return mysqli_query($dbs[$usedb], $sql);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use it procedurally like that:

```
$res = mysqli_query($sql);
```

It expects: (SRC: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

```
 mixed mysqli_query ( mysqli $link , string $query [, int $resultmode = MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT ] )
```

So, you're missing the first parameter.

Since you're returning the object.  I would change your private function 'query' to:

```
$mysql = $this->dbconnect($usedb);
$res = $mysql->query($sql);
```