# MySQL, COUNT on base from $_SESSION['username']

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

The problem I want to solve is that I want to count how many times the same username appears in 2 or more tables.

The username that i want to search for needs to be selected from `$_SESSION['username']`

```
First Table
| id | username |  date |
| 1  |   Mart   |28-5-13|
| 2  |   farm   |27-5-13|
| 3  |   Mart   |29-5-13|

Second Table
| 1  |   Mart   |22-5-13|
| 1  |   Mart   |25-5-13|
| 1  |   farm   |24-5-13|
```

Lets see, my `$_SESSION['username'] = 'Mart'`

How do I count the number of times the same username 'Mart' appeared in the two tables?

Is it something like?

```
$bloo = mysql_query('SELECT COUNT("username") FROM events AND Good WHERE username = "'.      mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['username']) . '"');
while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($bloo))
```

Or am I on the wrong track?

Any help is appreciated! Thank you

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://www.brightmeup.info/article.php?a_id=2).

Comment: you need to use UNION to combine the results of 2 queries. Do one query for each table.

Comment: sorry, 1 database 2 tables!

Comment: If you have fresh installed (latest) Apache server then you have to use `mysqli_` or `PDO`. `mysql_` is depreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this where `first_table` and `second_table` are the 2 tables you mentioned ("sorry, 1 database 2 tables! "):

```
SELECT
    SUM(c)
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) as c FROM first_table WHERE username = 'Mart'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT COUNT(*) as c FROM second_table WHERE username = 'Mart'
) as tmp
```

Comment: count the number of occurrences of 'Mart' username in 2 tables and then sum it up , i assumed this is what you needed

Answer (score 0):

All databases is in the same severs or not?! because i thinks that the best solution to the  seperated server is to use Web Services... but if it isn't, you have just to add two values from two query.

[Connect to multiple mysql DataBases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274892/how-do-you-connect-to-multiple-mysql-databases-on-a-single-webpage)

```
$dbh1 = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password); 
$dbh2 = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password, true); 

mysql_select_db('database1', $dbh1);
mysql_select_db('database2', $dbh2);

$res1 = mysql_query('select count(*) from tablename WHERE username="username"', $dbh1);
$res2 = mysql_query('select count(*) from tablename WHERE username="username', $dbh2);

$val1 = mysql_fetch_row($res1);
$val2 = mysql_fetch_row($res2);

$sum = $val1[0] + $val2[0];
```