# How to insert data into 2 database?

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to insert data into 2 tables which are in different database. But I'm not able to connect to the second database.

```
$con1 = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db1");

$sql_1 = "insert into enquiry(name,email,phone,subject,message,service_category) values('aa','aa@gg.com','12344','xxx','ddd','ddd')";

$res_1 = mysqli_query($con1,$sql_1);

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db2");

$sql = "insert into customers(cname,cphone,cemail) values('$name','$phone','$email')";

$res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
```

Comment: Check the result from `mysqli_connect()` and if the function fails, post the error message with `mysqli_connect_errno()`.

Comment: Please refer this url https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17788659/how-to-insert-data-in-two-different-tables-of-two-different-database-in-php

Comment: im using mysqli

Comment: As long as the databases are on the same instance (they both connect to `localhost`) and the correct permissions - you can just and the database name as a prefix `insert into db1.enquiry` and `insert into db2.customers`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a single connection

```
$db = new mysqli($host,$user,$pass);
```

When selecting the DB use this

```
mysqli_select_db('DB_NAME', $db);
```

You Code

```
$con1 = mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password");
/* For the DB1 */
mysqli_select_db('DB_NAME1', $con1);
$sql_1 = "insert into 
enquiry(name,email,phone,subject,message,service_category) 
values('aa','aa@gg.com','12344','xxx','ddd','ddd')";
$res_1 = mysqli_query($con1,$sql_1);

/* For the DB2 */
mysqli_select_db('DB_NAME2', $con1);
$sql = "insert into customers(cname,cphone,cemail) 
values('$name','$phone','$email')";
$res = mysqli_query($con1,$sql);
```

Comment: can u say how should i run the sql query?