# Copy table from different server using cron

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I have a live server and a test server right now, and I need to copy a table from live to test using cron because it needs to run every hour. I've created a `php` script and tested it using localhost, and it works fine, but when I test at live server, it doesn't work.

I suspect because when at localhost, although it between different database but still using the same server connection. and I'm using `phpmyadmin`.

Edit: Here the code

```
<?php
/* fill in your source database name */
$database = "xxx";
$dbhost1 = "xxx";
$dbusr1 = "xxx";
$dbpas1 = "xxx";
/* fill in your target database name */
$database2 = "yyy";
$dbhost2 = "yyy";
$dbusr2 = "yyy";
$dbpas2 = "yyy";

if ($connect = mysqli_connect($dbhost1, $dbusr1, $dbpas1)) 
{
    mysql_select_db($database, $connect);
    echo "connected to xxx<br/>";
}
else { die("Source database fail to connect: Please try again" . mysql_error());}

if ($connect2 = mysqli_connect($dbhost2, $dbusr2, $dbpas2)) 
{
    mysql_select_db($database2, $connect2);
    echo "connected to yyy<br/>";
}
else { die("Target database fail to connect 1: " . mysql_error());}
set_time_limit(0);

$tables = array("coupon");
$tables_no = count($tables); 

for ($i=0; $i < $tables_no ; $i++){
    $tab = $tables[$i];
    $query_table1 = "SELECT * FROM $database.$tab";
    $query_table2 = "SELECT * FROM $database2.$tab";

    $source= mysql_query($query_table1);
    $destination= mysql_query($query_table2);

    if ($source <= $destination){
    echo 'aaa';
        while($row_table1 = mysql_fetch_array($source)){
            // var_dump ($row_table1);
            // if statement
        }
    }
    else {echo 'dalam else';}
} 
?>
```

Comment: "doesn't work" isn't an explanation of the issue.

Comment: showing some script could help, you can mask out the confidential  details...

Comment: Sorry. I put the script at test server and when I run it, it seems that it can't read the query statement. I put the script for help. Thanks

Comment: Please see my answer here (And also try to use mysqli instead!)

Connect To Multiple Database

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18393200/is-it-possible-to-connect-to-multiple-database-e-g-database1-database2/18393755#18393755

Comment: Why go to the trouble of writing a script when there is a replication mechanism (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html)

Comment: @EdHeal I need to only copy one or two table every hour and not the whole table in the database. Is the link given also can be used on that? Sorry to ask because I'm not familiar with that script.

Comment: @kiki - Replication will mean that if somebody updates the live database (delete/insert/update a row) that will be filtered down to the test one. There is no script required. Just need to configure things. You can even use it for backup etc.. just follow the links from the link. (you can use it for load balancing!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second connect is  killing your 1st one. if using **mysql_connect**, please check the manual for variable to pass in to avoid this...

```
if ($connect = mysql_connect($dbhost1, $dbusr1, $dbpas1)) 
{
    mysql_select_db($database, $connect);
    echo "connected to xxx<br/>";
}
else { die("Source database fail to connect: Please try again" . mysql_error());}

if ($connect2 = mysql_connect($dbhost2, $dbusr2, $dbpas2, true)) 
{
    mysql_select_db($database2, $connect2);
    echo "connected to yyy<br/>";
}
```

And to retrieve results from each DB, use their respective resource...

```
$result1 = mysql_query($connect1, $sql_query1);

$result2 = mysql_query($connect2, $sql_query2);
```

Comment: I've try using your code but still the same error happens. It seems like it stop to read the code at ** while($row_table1 = mysql_fetch_array($source)){ ** line. the ** echo 'aaa'; ** line is printed and stop at while statement after that

Comment: Hi, editing above what else went wrong, I think u need to specify resource for your query

Comment: Great! yes, need to specify the resource of query. Thank you for your immediate help.