# Connecting to two Database tables and updating both

Tags: php

I'm trying to connect too two databases, the reason for this is because I am creating a redeem  code system. Once somebody has brought something from me with paypal. They get a redeem code (I give them), then once they type the redeem code

1) It updates MySQL Changing (The Table Redeem)

```
CODE | PRIZE | EXPIRED | USED_BY |
```

To

```
CODE | PRIZE | 0 | $_SESSION['username']
```

If `Expired = 0` code is no longer active if It equals 1 it is active.
If they successfully redeem the code It updates `EXPIRED = 1` and cannot be used. It also updated `User` table and set `credits+PRIZE`.

Anybody know how to do it?

With PHP,

Thanks,
Hope you can help!

Comment: You connect to databases, not tables. While this *could* be solved by simple conditional logic (*and transactions*), it might be better to rethink the "credits+prize" column design.

Comment: You need to show what you have done so far and specifically explain the problems you are having.  SO is not a free coding service.

Comment: this is a poor database design. If other parts of this is not in production. This programming should stop until further research and better database design is put together.

Comment: To connect multiple databases:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274892/how-do-you-connect-to-multiple-mysql-databases-on-a-single-webpage  but as the guys suggested, it's not a good database design.

Answer (score 0):

try to do you connection like this

```
 $link=mysql_connect("server", "username", "password");
 mysql_select_db("db_name");
```

then do your queries 
and then close the connection 
with the code

```
 mysql_close($link);
```

and do the same for the other database

Answer (score 0):

Here's is a solution.
update the Redeem table with following SQL:
update Redeem set EXPIRED=0 , USED_BY=$_SESSION['username'] where EXPIRED=1 limit 1;

this SQL updates only one available record from EXPIRED=1 to EXPIRED=0,and gives it to the user. 
after this,you can use:
select * from Redeem where USED_BY=$_SESSION['username']

to find the record  that belongs to this user,and then you know how to update the user credit.

if the first update failed,the user data will not be updated.

However, the column EXPIRED  should be renamed as "INACTIVE",and you should learn how to use transactions and PHP exceptions. Google them.