# 2 mysqli include files on one page

Tags: php, mysqli

Wondering if it is possible to include two mysqli connection include php files on the same page.

I have a basic site I am using to learn/develop in php with mysql.  I have one database for storing user information and another for website specific information.  I can use both independently from each other without any issues.

Config.php:

```
DEFINE("HOST", "127.0.0.1");
DEFINE("USER","root");
DEFINE("PASS","");
DEFINE("DB","sv");
```

connect.php:

```
include_once 'config.php'; 
$mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASS, DB);
```

sec_config.php:

```
define("HOST", "127.0.0.1");    
define("USER", "sec_user");    
define("PASSWORD", "");  
define("DATABASE", "svn");
```

sec_connect.php:

```
include_once 'sec_config.php';   // As functions.php is not included
$mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
```

My php pages can successfully query and display data from these connections. My index.php currently contained included the sec_connect, I am trying to add another php page which (within itself) includes

```
include_once("connect.php");
```

When I try and run the page I receive

```
mysqli::mysqli(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.
mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: ...as above
mysqli::prepare(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in
Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in
```

I have simply commented out the above include_once to get everything working again.

I am using windows with xamp for dev, I have tried accessing via localhost and my ip address and I receive the same error.  I have tried editing the hosts file and I have also tried amending the values in the connect files to be unique (changed back as it didnt help).

Hopefully this is the righ question to ask: Is it possible to include two mysqli database connections via different includes from my index.php page?

Comment: This might help you out... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274892/how-do-you-connect-to-multiple-mysql-databases-on-a-single-webpage

Comment: Thanks, a bit more googling led me to this which looks very similar but displays the mysqli syntax: http://schoolsofweb.com/how-to-connect-to-multiple-mysql-databases-on-a-single-web-page-in-php/

Answer (score 3):

This should work, provided you refer to the two different connections with different variables (they are two distinct instances after all).

For example:

**file1.php**

```
$db1 = new mysqli(HOST1, USER1, PASSWORD1, DATABASE1);
```

**file2.php**

```
$db2 = new mysqli(HOST2, USER2, PASSWORD2, DATABASE2);
```

**file3.php**

```
require "file1.php"
require "file2.php"

$result1 = $db1->query("SELECT * FROM table");

$result2 = $db2->query("SELECT * FROM some_other_table");
```

Comment: I assume it isn't a problem to have file 3 broken into file3 (for $DB1 queries) and file4 (for $DB2 queries) and then display results from both on file5 (index.php) via include_once file3/4 - does that make sense?  Trying it now

Comment: I am still struggling with this - I've done the above but it still produces the same as soon as I include my 2nd db query.php file on the index.php (along side the existing sec one)