# How to make the same database query on two different databases?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make a query on two different databases with php and mysql. You can see my approach bellow, but it does not work. Both the queries are being executed on the first database. Why does this happen?

```
mysql_connect(HOST,USER,PASSWORD);
mysql_select_db(DB_1);

mysql_query("some query");

mysql_select_db(DB_2);

mysql_query("some query");
```

Comment: 1) better upgrade your mysql_* code (deprecated) to mysqli_* or pdo. 2) to see what you've done wrong we need your code or at least part of it. 3) you can always not connect to db and use (example) SELECT * FROM dbname.dbtable on each Query.

Comment: Use `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set('display_errors',1);`. Then add a print error condition to the connect, select and query.

Comment: Please, [don't use `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php), They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://us1.php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://us1.php.net/mysqli). [This article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274892/how-do-you-connect-to-multiple-mysql-databases-on-a-single-webpage

Comment: 2) that is the code.
3) that would destroy my whole application :(

Answer (score 3):

You should make sure the resource is updated and used:

```
$link = mysql_connect(HOST,USER,PASSWORD);
mysql_select_db(DB_1, $link);

mysql_query("some query", $link);

mysql_select_db(DB_2, $link);

mysql_query("some query", $link);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an absolute query:

```
SELECT field FROM db1.table ...
SELECT field FROM db2.table ...
```

e.g. you don't need to use `select_db()`. That merely sets the DEFAULT database to use, but you can easily query other databases by using the absolute `db.table.field` naming convention.

Comment: Thanks that's a good point. Sadly it would mean too much of a change in my code to do it now. At least I'll know I can do that.