# how to connect more than two databases i.e (3 Databases) in php

Tags: php

```
$con1=mysql_pconnect("localhost","root","") or die("not connected to server");

mysql_select_db("wheels",$con1) or die("not connected to database");

$con2=mysql_pconnect("localhost","root","",true) or die("not connected to server");

mysql_select_db("pakbikes",$con2) or die("not connected to database");

$con3=mysql_pconnect("localhost","root","", true) or die("not connected to server");

mysql_select_db("olx",$con3) or die("not connected to database");
```

but its not working it only connect 2 databases...

Comment: This sounds like a server setting problem, assuming the database names are all correct.

Comment: You refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274892/how-do-you-connect-to-multiple-mysql-databases-on-a-single-webpage

Comment: Setting up multiple handles is pointless, unless you have distinct access accounts. Mysql allows to mix them in queries with `FROM dbname.tblname` more easily. No need to micromanage that throughout the application.