# Multiple database connections with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to connect to several databases at the same time and am having problems. This query works fine with my local site. (It doesn't have a username or password, thus the "root, root.")

```
$dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=gbase;charset=utf8";
 $opt = array(
  PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
  PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
 );

 $pdo = new PDO($dsn,'root','root', $opt);
```

I used [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274892/how-do-you-connect-to-multiple-mysql-databases-on-a-single-webpage) as a guide in creating a multiple-database query. I replaced all the code above with this:

```
try {
 $db1 = new PDO('mysql:dbname=gbase;host=localhost', 'root', 'root');
 $db2 = new PDO('mysql:dbname=glife;host=localhost', 'root', 'root');
} catch (PDOException $ex) {
  echo 'Connection failed: ' . $ex->getMessage();
}
```

But I get these error messages:

**Notice:** Undefined variable: pdo in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/gx/index.php on line 164

**Fatal error:** Call to a member function prepare() on null in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/gx/index.php on line 164

And this is line 64:

```
$stm = $pdo->prepare("SELECT A.Site, A.URL, A.Title, A.Article
 FROM 1_about A
```

I suspect that I need to somehow integrate my new code with my original code, rather than simply replace it. However, I don't understand what's going on. Can someone show me the correct way to write a multiple-database query?

**Edit: Below is the entire code I'm using.**

```
try {
 $db1 = new PDO('mysql:dbname=geobase;host=localhost', 'root', 'root');
 $db2 = new PDO('mysql:dbname=geolife;host=localhost', 'root', 'root');
} catch (PDOException $ex) {
 echo 'Connection failed: ' . $ex->getMessage();
}

$stm = $pdo->prepare("SELECT A.Site, A.URL, A.Title, A.Article
 FROM 1_about A
 WHERE A.Site = 'g1' AND A.URL = 'webranger'");
$stm->execute(array(
 // 'MyURL'=>'%'.$MyURL.'%'
));

while ($row = $stm->fetch())
{
 $Article = $row['Article'];
}

echo $Article;
```

Comment: So you've changed `$pdo` to `$db1` and `$db2` respectively... use those instead?

Comment: Yes, actually the variable name is wrong. If is just a typo, please show all code, or at least the part where you create the PDO instances and execute the queries.

Comment: Yes, actually the variable name is wrong. If is just a typo, please show all code, or at least the part where you create the PDO instances and execute the queries.

Comment: where does the var `$pdo `come from?

Comment: @ Vitor Luis - I edited my post, pasting the complete code at the end. @ Robbie and RamRaider - I don't understand where or how to insert $pdo. Replacing $db1 and $db2 with $pdo doesn't make sense (to me, at least).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You trying to call a function from an undefined object. On you case, you created two PDO instances, on `$db1` and `$db2`.

Some lines below, you are trying to call the `prepare` function from a variable called `$pdo`. But in the code that you show to us, the `$pdo` variable doesn't exists.

So, what you need to do is change the `$pdo` variable for the `$db1` variable or `$db2` variable. Depends which connection you want to use. Like this:

```
$stm = $db1->prepare("SELECT A.Site, A.URL, A.Title, A.Article
 FROM 1_about A
 WHERE A.Site = 'g1' AND A.URL = 'webranger'");
```

Just that! :D

Comment: Now I'm getting the error "Notice: Undefined variable: Article in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/gx/index.php on line 177" but that's probably just a simple bug I can fix. One more question, though - what if I need to query tables from two different databases at the same time? For example, suppose I wanted to join a table from Database1 with a table from Database2?

Comment: Well i never tried before, but i think you can put the name of the database in the front f the table name like: `database1.table1` and `database2.table2`

Comment: OK, that makes sense.