# How to Connect two data base mysql in same time

Tags: php, mysql

I use this in a file called `connect.php`:

```
$username_mysql = "root";
$password_mysql = "";
$database_mysql = "bdd_imvert";
//$database_mysql = "imprimvert_renouvellement";
$db = @mysql_connect($hostname_mysql, $username_mysql, $password_mysql) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($database_mysql,$db);

$hostnameivert_mysql = "localhost";
$usernameivert_mysql = "root";
$passwordivert_mysql = "";
$databaseivert_mysql = "ivert";
//$database_mysql = "imprimvert_renouvellement";
$db1 = @mysql_connect($hostnameivert_mysql, $usernameivert_mysql, $passwordivert_mysql) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($databaseivert_mysql,$db1);`
```

I include it in the a page containing:

```
$sql = "select * from ivert_users where id=".GetSQLValueString($user_id,"int");
$re = @mysql_query($sql,$db)
```

I get an error when I do this however:

> 'ivert.ivert_users' does not exist

I am not sure why I get this error, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274892/how-do-you-connect-to-multiple-mysql-databases-on-a-single-webpage

Comment: Are the 2 databases on the same mysql server?

Comment: Btw, in the mysql_query() call that produces the error, use $db1 instead of $db as connection parameter.

Comment: i do update true  to seconde connexion but i have not for the first query :$re_tri = @mysql_query($sql,$db) or die ( mysql_error()."<br>$sql" ); i have die

Comment: @Shadow i am not understand how can use $db1 instead $db?

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with your code. I tried the same and it is working for me. There must be some problem with your query. Because your error message shows that connection happened but your query returned an error. Refer this It might help.

Or the second reason it can be is you haven't defined host for the first DB.

```
<?php 

$hostnameivert_mysql = "localhost";
$username_mysql      = "root";
$password_mysql      = "pma";
$database_mysql      = "olivenation";
$db                  = @mysql_connect($hostname_mysql, $username_mysql, $password_mysql) or die(mysql_error());

mysql_select_db($database_mysql,$db);

echo ("<pre>");print_r($db);echo("</pre>");

$hostnameivert_mysql = "localhost";
$usernameivert_mysql = "root";
$passwordivert_mysql = "pma";
$databaseivert_mysql = "practical";

$db1=@mysql_connect($hostnameivert_mysql, $usernameivert_mysql, $passwordivert_mysql) or die(mysql_error());

mysql_select_db($databaseivert_mysql,$db1);

echo ("<pre>");print_r($db1);echo("</pre>");

$sql = "select * from product_master where id=1";
$re  = @mysql_query($sql,$db);

echo ("<pre>");print_r(mysql_fetch_array($re));echo("</pre>");

$sql = "select * from users";
$re  = @mysql_query($sql,$db1);

echo ("<pre>");print_r(mysql_fetch_array($re));echo("</pre>");

?>
```

Comment: i do that but i have error $sql="insert into referent (oldReferentId,genderReferent,firstnameReferent,lastnameReferent,emailReferent,phoneReferent,faxReferent,type,adressReferent,supportOrganization,zipCode,cityReferent,countryReferent,mailAverti,blocked,published,validateRight)
   VALUES (".GetSQLValueString($tb_user['id'],"int").",'NULL',".$tb_user['name'].",".$tb_user['username'].",".$tb_user['email'].",'','',".$tb_user['usertype'].",'','','','','',".$tb_user['block'].",'0','0')";
      $test=@mysql_query($sql,$db1) or die( mysql_error() . "<br>$sql" );