# Multiple Database with PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database

We have a Registration database and a list of project database (each project has a different database).
The registration database is used to get the details of username and password and connect the project database based on the log in details.

We like to keep both database connected at the same time.

How can we do that?
Thanks!

Comment: Kindly check this answer of @Tom http://stackoverflow.com/a/274919/3081659. Great explanation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you connect to multiple MySQL databases on a single webpage?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274892/how-do-you-connect-to-multiple-mysql-databases-on-a-single-webpage)

Comment: Thanks man, will check.