# How to delete image from two different database and folder with PHPMYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

// i have two tables like,projects and projectfiles.

projects fields are:

id,name,alice,catg,img;

//insertin the image in the folder 'upload'

projectfiles fields are :

id,name,img

//inserting the image in the folder 'image'

so,how delete the data from projects and projectfiles even from directory.

```
<?php 

    include('dbconfig1.php');


    if(!$db)
    {
        die(mysqli_error());
    }


    $sql = "select * from projects";
    $result = $db->query($sql);


    if(isset($_GET['id']))
    {
        $selectSql = "select * from projects where id = ".$_GET['id'];
        $rsSelect = mysqli_query($db,$selectSql);
        $getRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rsSelect);

        $getIamgeName = $getRow['img'];

        $createDeletePath = "upload/".$getIamgeName;

        if(unlink($createDeletePath))
        {
            $deleteSql = "delete from projects where id = ".$getRow['id'];
            $rsDelete = mysqli_query($db, $deleteSql);  

            if($rsDelete)
            {
                header('location:projects.php?success=true');
                exit();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $errorMsg = "Unable to delete Image";
        }

    }


?>
        ?>

        <?php 
        if(isset($_GET['success']) && $_GET['success'] == 'true')
        {
        ?>
            <div class="alert alert-success">
                <?php 
                    echo "Images has been deleted sucessfully";
                ?>
            </div>
        <?php 
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: this code isonly for single table and folder

Comment: use this topic for connecting to 2 database
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274892/how-do-you-connect-to-multiple-mysql-databases-on-a-single-webpage

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you connect to multiple MySQL databases on a single webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274892/how-do-you-connect-to-multiple-mysql-databases-on-a-single-webpage)

Comment: the above is vulnerable to sql injection. Is the above really for 2 databases or 2 tables in a single database?

Comment: my question is ...i have 2 tables in one databse.i want to delete the whole data drom both tables in one query

Comment: Use a transaction and parameterize your queries.

Comment: Question details go in your question as an edit ; not as comments under the question. Then delete your comments.

Comment: Consider whether performing a hard delete of data is something you really want your users to be allowed to do